# Overriding package name in sbt 0.11.2

Tags: java, sbt

I have an sbt project building a jar, which works fine except that the filename produced by `sbt package` is `recentusers_2.9.1-0.1.jar`. Can I override this? I just want to remove the Scala version from the name, since my project source is pure Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a pure Java project, use:

```
crossPaths := false
```

to not cross-version artifacts or paths and:

```
autoScalaLibrary := false
```

to not add a dependency on the Scala library automatically.

Comment: `crossPaths := false` was the thing for me. Thanks.